# Exporting parent report's subreports into a single Excel sheet?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm using SQL2008 R2.

I have a parent report, with a sub-report. The user is prompted for a date and variable number of "areas". For each area selected, that area gets its own page which is the sub-report containing that area's data.

When exporting, each area gets its own sheet.

In SSRS, how can I force the dynamic number of sub-reports into a single Excel sheet on export?

There could be hundreds of sheets generated and I can't expect the user to cut/paste the data into a single sheet every day.

Specific example:
I pick Pittsburgh West and Pittsburgh East, and export. Sheet 1 is Pittsburgh West data, Sheet 2 is Pittsburgh East data.

I want to maintain the headers but have all of the selected area's data on Sheet 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SSRS 2008R2, you can set page breaks to be enabled or disabled based on the format used to render the report.

Typically you would have a table with groups to control page breaks. By clicking on the group and looking at its properties you see there is a PageBreak -> Disabled property. In your case, you would disable this for Excel only:

```
=IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL", True, False)
```

[image]

Other objects like Rectangles that can control page breaks can be configured the same way.

Comment: I tried that on both of the parent report (its rectangle and tablix) as well as the sub-report (two tablixes) and it still splits them into sheets.

Comment: Perhaps you have page breaks in multiple places. To troubleshoot I would remove any page breaks as an interim and see how this renders to test to see if there are other unexpected ones.

Comment: I went to the properties of the row in both parent and sub-reports, and remove the respective page breaks. Both were set to "Between each instance of a group". So that takes care of it, but it does it both in the report and the export. Do you know of a way to make the rows' page break user toggled so that some users can export with multiple sheets and others with a single sheet?

Comment: actually I think I got it. I was having difficulty setting the Tablix Member property in the properties tab. Let me confirm and I'll accept your answer. Thanks again for the help.